# How to Insert Images In Birt At Runtime Language (Java)

Tags: java, birt

I am able to Create a Birt Report in My Rcp Application But the Problem is I was Unable to add Images into My Table Data (Cell Data)

The Path or Location for the Image is in My Workspace. My Question is How can I set a Path or Location For the Image Which will Display In the Report Table. We have SetURL Method for Image Handler but it was Giving an Error As Follows

```
TextItemHandle cellData = null;
CellHandle contenCell = null;
contentCell = (CellHandle) tabledetail.getCells().get(0);
cellData = designFactory.newTextItem(value);
cellData.setContent(value.replace(" ", ""));
cellData.setProperty("canShrink", "false");

cellData.getPropertyHandle(StyleHandle.FONT_SIZE_PROP).setIntValue(10);

image = designFactory.newImage("");
image.setURL("platform:/plugin/com.****.reportgeneration/images/Information-icon.gif");
contentCell.getContent().add(cellData);   
contentCell.getContent().add(image);
```

Full Stack of Exception

> org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2375)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:191)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
>       at com.****.reportgeneration.popup.actions.ModuleReportGeneration.createReportFolder(ModuleReportGeneration.java:465)
>       at com.****.reportgeneration.popup.actions.ModuleReportGeneration.access$0(ModuleReportGeneration.java:402)
>       at com.****.reportgeneration.popup.actions.ModuleReportGeneration$1.run(ModuleReportGeneration.java:325)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
>   Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: invalid flag after regular expression (#1)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:77)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.error(DefaultErrorReporter.java:64)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:188)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:166)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:223)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:210)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:203)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.TokenStream.readRegExp(TokenStream.java:921)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.primaryExpr(Parser.java:2798)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.memberExpr(Parser.java:2406)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Parser.java:2304)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Parser.java:2229)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Parser.java:2213)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Parser.java:2194)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Parser.java:2169)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Parser.java:2141)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Parser.java:2130)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Parser.java:2119)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Parser.java:2108)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Parser.java:2097)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Parser.java:2086)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Parser.java:2062)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Parser.java:2033)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.expr(Parser.java:2012)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1039)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.nameOrLabel(Parser.java:1793)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1032)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:901)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:540)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:478)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2348)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1335)
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1324)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.javascript.JavascriptEngine$3.run(JavascriptEngine.java:240)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.javascript.JavascriptEngine$3.run(JavascriptEngine.java:1)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.javascript.JavascriptEngine.compile(JavascriptEngine.java:236)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.javascript.JavascriptEngine.compile(JavascriptEngine.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.ScriptContext.compile(ScriptContext.java:153)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.compile(ExecutionContext.java:779)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.evaluate(ExecutionContext.java:713)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ReportItemExecutor.evaluateString(ReportItemExecutor.java:297)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ImageItemExecutor.handleURIImage(ImageItemExecutor.java:261)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ImageItemExecutor.handleImage(ImageItemExecutor.java:214)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ImageItemExecutor.execute(ImageItemExecutor.java:111)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableBandLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableBandLM.java:67)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.layoutChildren(HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.java:46)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.layoutChildren(HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.java:46)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
>       at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:181)

Comment: Please provide some source code with what you are trying currently, and the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Hi Florian , I have Updated My post Please Check Once .Thanks For your Concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextItemHandle nText = designFactory.newTextItem(null);
nText.setContentType(DesignChoiceConstants.TEXT_CONTENT_TYPE_HTML);
nText.setContent("<img src="+ "D:\\***Ws_16-11-18\\com.** (*.***.projectcreation\\icons\\sample.gif" + " />");
contentCell.getContent().add(nText);
```

This code worked for me to insert Image